# Scheduling MySQL Workbench to execute and export on a daily basis

Tags: mysql-workbench

Here's my question.

I have a couple scripts (very simple stuff; select queries) that I run in MySQL Workbench which I can than export to CSVs. What I want to know is if it is possible to schedule MySQL Workbench to run the scripts and export to CSVs at a specific time everyday.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) or if you want to use the command line, then an [`at`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313565) job should do the trick. On Window 7, the [`schtasks`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx) (see also [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx)) should be of use.

MySQL Workbench is not for doing this, except if you have the [Enterprise Edition](https://www.mysql.com/common/images/products/MySQL_Workbench_Admin_Backup_Windows.gif).

Comment: Correct, however the enterprise edition (its name is actually: MySQL Workbench SE, standard edition, in oppostion to CE, community edition) uses MEB (MySQL Enterprise Backup) instead of mysqldump.

Comment: @MikeLischke  
Thanks for clarifying that Mike. BTW, big fan of Virtual Treeview back in the good old Delphi days. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use MySQL Workbench to write and test the scripts, but then use an OS-native script running utility to run the scripts at specific times. For example, on Linux you might use [cron](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cron), which is simple to use (there are also tools designed to make it even easier).